# Git clone fail while commit working fine in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I am getting the below error while trying to commit in gitlab. Is there any prior environmental setup I need to do before the commit?

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:474:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml (Errno::EACCES)
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:474:in `open'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:474:in `load_file'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_config.rb:7:in `initialize'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:13:in `new'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:6:in `require_relative'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_net.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:4:in `require_relative'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_shell.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell:22:in `<main>'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that permission is denied to the GitLab Shell config file. Make sure the file `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml` is owned by `git` so GitLab Shell can read the configuration during push.

It's curious that this file has a permission problem to begin with, though. If you changed any configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` then be sure to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Also, avoid messing with anything inside `/opt/gitlab`.